# handle UI State with Stateflow and ViewModel in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, stateflow, dataclasses

as it is recomended in lots of documents and tutorials we should define ui states as varaiables of a data class and define it as a MutableStateFlow in our viewModel and whenever we want to update the screen whith new state we should update the MutableStateFlow with that data class.

for exmple :

`data class UiState( val isLoading : Boolean = false , val moviesList : List<Movie> = emptyList(), val listTitle : String = "popular")`

in viewModel :

`var uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState()) private set`

and for updating :
`uiState.update {it.copy(isLoading = true)}`

now here is the question :
i'm wondering that isn't it a bad practice to copy the data class whenever we want to update the state and Update just one property, leave the rest as they were . imagine a complicated screen that has ten states and we are creating a new instance of data class just for updating one of its property each time . as each copy instantiate a new instance, doesn't this cause some memory leak issue ?

isn't it better to provide a separate stateFlow for each state and each time we just update that state instead of making a new instance of a data class by copying that.

`var titleState = MutableStateFlow("popular") private set`

`var movieListState = MutableStateFlow<List<Movie>>(emptyList<Movie>()) private set`

`var isLoadingState = MutableStateFlow(false) private set`

and for updating just call :

`titleState.value = "upComing"`

Comment: i've just red an article in medium which was exactly about what i asked in my question and as it's mentioned both ways have their own pros and cons . 
i think it's worth to use multiple states instead of single state data class .

https://proandroiddev.com/android-viewmodel-single-state-or-not-d914f962d44c